# Remove whole object from array in vue

Tags: arrays, object, vue.js

Right now I have an array with multiple companies.

Like this but only 1:

```
[{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Lorem",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum"
}]
```

I loop through the companies and pass the company with the delete function.

```
<a @click="deleteCompany(company)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

deleteCompany(company) {
    Vue.delete(company, 'name');
}
```

As of right now it only deletes the name.. but how do I delete the whole object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array of companies is in the data for the Vue, you would remove it this way:

```
deleteCompany(company) {
    // find the index of the company object in the companies array
    const where = this.companies.findIndex(c => c === company)
    // splice the object from the array
    this.companies.splice(where, 1)
}
```

This could be shortened a bit if you chose to pass the index of the company to the function instead of the company itself.

You could also use [Vue.delete](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete), but it is not necessary in this case; splice will do. If you wanted to use Vue.delete, it would look like this: `Vue.delete(this.companies, where)`.